# assertion failure, list iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++

I'm getting an assertion failure "list iterator not dereferencable" from this line in the following code:

iter2 = iter->vertex_list.erase(iter2);

I'm not really sure why this is happening, I've made sure the list is not empty. Full code follows:

```
void Map_Quad_List::Vertex_List_Duplicate_Removal() {
    for (std::list<Map_Polygon>::iterator iter = map_polygon_list.begin(); iter != map_polygon_list.end(); iter++) { //iterate through polygons
        std::vector<XMFLOAT3> position_list; //list of vertices already tried
            for (std::list<Vertex>::iterator iter2 = iter->vertex_list.begin(); iter2 != iter->vertex_list.end(); iter2++ ) {//iterate through vertices
                bool dup = false;
                for (std::vector<XMFLOAT3>::iterator pos_list_iter = position_list.begin(); pos_list_iter != position_list.end(); pos_list_iter++) { //check vertex against position_list
                    if ((!position_list.empty()) && (XMFLOAT3_Comparison(*pos_list_iter, iter2->position))) { //if vertex already exists in position_list
                        iter2 = iter->vertex_list.erase(iter2); //remove vertex from polygon's vertex_list
                        dup = true;
                    }
                }
                if (dup == false) //if there is not a duplicate in position_list, add it to position_list
                position_list.push_back(iter2->position);
            }

    }
}
```

map_polygon_list is a std::list of class type Map_Polygon

Map_Polygon class has a std::list of class type Vertex

Vertex is a class made up of a XMFLOAT3 (position) and a XMFLOAT4 (color), this function only deals with position (XMFLOAT3)

XMFLOAT3_Comparison is a function that compare two XMFLOAT3 and returns true if they are the same

Comment: can you debug and see what is the code around the assert that is popping it up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `iter2` might go to `iter->vertex_list.end()` within the inner most for loop, this would lead to this assert, since the item pointed to is null.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even if there was only one element in the list and it is erased (moving the iterator to the "past-the-end" element) I'm not dereferencing it after that. Also, I tried changing the if statement to if ((!position_list.empty()) && (iter2 != iter->vertex_list.end()) && (XMFLOAT3_Comparison(*pos_list_iter, iter2->position))) to no effect.

Comment: Your inner loop might erase more than once, so one iteration, it moves past end, 2nd iteration assert. Does this sound likely?

Comment: @rm ok, if the new `if` made no difference then perhaps its something else. Did you try to debug and step through?